# Can anyone clarify: Is steady_clock trustworthy between threads in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, system-clock

Can anyone please confirm (or deny) whether the steady_clock is "trustworthy" between threads? According to the article [Is the epoch of steady_clock relative to when the operating system starts? or to the process itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30882953/is-the-epoch-of-steady-clock-relative-to-when-the-operating-system-starts-or-to/33758235#33758235), there was some discussion about whether or not the steady_clock was trustworthy at the system level, between processes. My question is, is the steady_clock at least trustworthy between threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the relevant part of the standard, `[time.clock.req]`, dictates that the clock *type* dictates the epoch so, as long as you're using `steady_clock`, threads are irrelevant:

> A `clock` is a bundle consisting of a `duration`, a `time_point`, and a function `now()` to get the current `time_point`. The origin of the clock’s `time_point` is referred to as the clock’s epoch.

It would be a poor state of affairs if you couldn't reliably get a `duration` by subtracting two `time_point` variables just because one was generated in a separate thread :-)

Note that this only applies within the scope of the standard. Since the question you linked to was to do with separate *processes,* the standard does not mandate behaviour one way or another.

This is no different to writing a binary `time_point` (or even an `int`) and expecting it to be the same when reading it back on a totally different system (for example, writing a little-endian `int` and trying to read it back on a big-endian system).

But the standard *does* cover threading so you can safely treat different `time_point` variable from the same clock type as being compatible.

Comment: Poor state of affairs it may or may not be. The problem is that the second answer to the post I provided to the URL to was never countered. And in fact, it was up-voted. So, that said, and let me be more specific: Assuming a thread spawns four threads, and the four threads post specific time_points based on events. And the parent thread has the appropriately synchronized access to those time_points. Can the parent thread trust that the steady_time values posted by each of the four threads represent  can be compared to each other?

Comment: @Weedware, that answer, and its question, pertain to separate *processes* and the answer is correct because the C++ standard does not care about processes (being outside of its scope means that it does not mandate behaviour). It *does* care a great deal about threads because threads are part of the standard itself. I'll update the answer to hopefully make that clearer.

Comment: So, in short, the answer to my question was yes.

Comment: In short, yes, it is. I just thought you'd like a little more support than "yes" :-)